# How can we ingest data from MongoDB to H2o cluster?

Tags: mongodb, h2o

I have around 2GB data in my local MongoDB database with one collection in the database. I want to ingest all these data from MongoDB database to standalone H2o cluster for building machine learning model. I am using python for data analysis in H2o. Could you please advise how can I proceed ?

Answer (score 0):

I've never works with H2O, but asumming it has no integration with mongo:

To me it looks like you should write the script that will:

1. Connect to mongo
2. Run the query and get the cursor
3. Iterate through the results, convert the object into the form that H2O understands and
4. Put into H2O (better in batches if H2O supports batch inserts)

Comment: I can export data to csv from mongo and after that I can take data from csv to H2O. But this is two way process. I am looking for any better solution for performance perspective.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is load the data in spark cluster using spark-mongodb connector and the comverting DataFrame to H2OFrame.
For detail please check http://docs.h2o.ai/sparkling-water/2.2/latest-stable/doc/tutorials/spark_h2o_conversions.html#converting-a-dataframe-into-an-h2oframe

After that use Sparkling Water to analyze the data.